# Bounding a weighted sum over primes by a sum over integers

Tags: prime-numbers, approximation, analytic-number-theory

According to my notes it follows immediately from the Prime Number Theorem that we can upper bound a sum over primes with weights $\log p$ by the corresponding sum over integers - for example,
$$\sum_{p>x}\frac{\log p}{p^2}\ll\sum_{n>x}\frac{1}{n^2}.$$
However this is not clear to me at all. I am not sure how to change it from a sum over primes to one over integers directly. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Do you know about partial summation?

Comment: Yes I do - although I'm not sure how to show this even with partial summation.

Comment: Recall that $\vartheta(x) = \sum_{p \leqslant x} \log p$. Can you write the left hand side in terms of $\vartheta$ using Abel's sum formula?